# PHP Function "opendir()" in Wordpress. Works in one file, but not in other

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, get, opendir

Alright, this will need a long explanation. Sorry if it's too long:

/////////////// INTRODUCTION ///////////////

There doesn't seem to be much information around about using `opendir()` within Wordpress and the way it should be implemented. However, after a couple hours of research, trial and error, I got it working on a custom page template.

I need it to fetch game thumbnail images from folders and output them as a grid, divided by categories (each folder is a category).

/////////////// MY APPROACH ///////////////

I created a function in `functions.php` that opens and reads a folder using the following relative path:

```
"wp-content/games/".$category."/"
```

Where `$category` is the argument of the function (defined by the user).

This is how my function looks like now:

```
function fetch_game_images($category){
    //$category = 'featured';
    $imageFiles = array();
    $extensions = array('.JPG','.PNG');
    $directory = "wp-content/games/".$category."/"; 
    $openDir = opendir($directory);

    while ($imgFile = readdir($openDir))
        {
        if ($imgFile <> '.' and $imgFile <> '..')
            {
            $extension = strtoupper(substr($imgFile, strrpos($imgFile, '.')));
            if (in_array($extension, $extensions))
                {
                $imageFiles[] = $imgFile;
                }
            }
        }

    closedir($openDir);

    foreach ($imageFiles as $k => $v)
    {
        $withoutExt = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $v);
        $hyphenlessName = str_replace("-"," ",$withoutExt);
        $formattedName = strlen($hyphenlessName) > 24 ? substr($hyphenlessName,0,24)."..." : $hyphenlessName;

        if ($category == 'featured'){
        if (strpos($formattedName,'netent') !== false) {$finalName = trim($formattedName, 'netent');}
        else if (strpos($formattedName,'mg') !== false) {$finalName = trim($formattedName, 'mg');}
        else { $finalName = $formattedName;}
        }
        else { $finalName = $formattedName;}

        echo '<div class="games-list-item"><div class="game-container">';
        echo '<a href=""><img src="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/'.$directory.'/'.$v.'" alt=""/>';
        echo '<h3>'.$finalName.'</h3></a>';
        echo '<div class="game-hover">';
        echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/'.$directory.'/'.$v.'" alt=""/>';
        echo '<div class="game-buttons-holder"><a class="play_now_btns" href="">Play Now</a><a class="free_play_btns" href="">Free Play</a></div></div><!--.game-hover-->';
        echo '</div><!--.game-container--></div><!--.games-list-item-->';
    }
}
```

/////////////// MY APPROACH RESULTS ///////////////

When I load the Wordpress Page using the Page Template that calls this function, it loads the images flawlessly.

But then, I have to change the games category dynamically using jQuery, I take the category/folder name, save it in a JavaScript variable and send it to a php that grabs it and passes it to the `fetch_game_images();` function.

My jQuery `GET` looks like this:

```
    $('#sidebar-list-menu li a').live('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var category = $(this).data('category');
        //alert(cat);
            //$('div.games-grid').html('<span class="loadingNotification">LOADING</span>');
            $.get("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/games-list-loader.php?category="+category,
                    function(data){
                    //alert(data);
                    //$('span.loadingNotification').remove();
                    $('div.games-grid').html(data); 
                }); 

    });
```

And the PHP File (located in the same theme directory) looks like this:

```
<?php $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );


                $cat = $_REQUEST['category'];
                fetch_game_images($cat);


?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
```

/////////////// THE ISSUE ///////////////

The issue is that when I click on the sidebar link that triggers the `GET` call and tries to fetch the data from the PHP, it outputs the following error:

```
Warning: opendir(wp-content/games/featured/) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in [...]
```

Which shouldn't happen at all, since both my Page Template and my custom PHP file are in the same directory and load Wordpress core to use `functions.php`.

/////////////// THE QUESTION ///////////////

Does anybody know what could be the reason behind this behaviour? I read most of the google results I could find about this `opendir()` error, but most of them seem to point at a wrong path, but mine seem to be correct.

Others say that it might be a permissions issue. But I got my folders set to 755 and the files to 644.

So, any help would be great! 
Thank you.

**<======== /////////// EDIT ///////// =========>**

Thanks to the help by **@CBroe**, I figured it out:

Instead of using a loose path like

```
"wp-content/games/".$category."/"
```

I changed it to a server-relative one

```
ABSPATH . "/wp-content/games/".$category."/"
```

And then I just changed the output to match the changes:

```
echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/games/'.$category.'/'.$v.'" alt=""/>';
```

This works from both locations and solved the `GET` issue.

Comment: Most likely your relative path is _not_ the correct one – usually happens when scripts are run from two different physical locations. Use a path relative to the server root.

Comment: And if you don’t _believe_ that it’s an issue with your path – even though PHP explicitly told you so – then make a debug output of `getcwd()` directly before calling `opendir`, and tell us what that yields in each of those two cases.

Comment: Sorry. I noticed the implicit arrogance in my _"my path is correct"_ statement (I edited it). I am trying your suggestions. Thank you! :)

Comment: Don’t worry, it’s a common beginners mistake :-) Over time you’ll see that PHP is usually right in what it tells you though. So, problem resolved, or do you need further help?

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I will edit my question to show the correct way. And I wish you would have put your comment as an answer so I could vote it up and give you some points :)

Comment: There you go … you’re welcome :-)

Comment: [**Don't include wp-load, please**](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your relative path is *not* the correct one – usually happens when scripts are run from two *different* physical locations.

Making a debug output of `getcwd()` directly before calling `opendir` will show you what directory the scripts are actually running in in both cases – and that location is the one used to “complete” the relative path, so if those don’t match it’s only natural one of them will fail.

Relative paths are always tricky that way. It’s usually preferable to use a path relative to the server root (starting with a `/`) to avoid such issues.